# How can I view how much charged is the battery of my Bose QuietComfort 35 II headphones on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate?

Tags: windows-7, audio, bluetooth, battery, headphones

How can I view how much charged is the battery of my Bose QuietComfort 35 II headphones on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate?

[image: d]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a software for Windows 7 named [Bluetooth Goodies](https://www.bluetoothgoodies.com/) to monitor the battery level on your Bluetooth headphone.

And for Windows 10, you don't need any kind of third party software. Go to Bluetooth and other devices page of Settings app, and if any bluetooth hardware is paired, its battery level and percentage will be shown beside the name of device.